# TypeScript issue with framer-motion 9+ and

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, framer-motion

When building a Next app using framer-motion 9.1.7 and 10.0, I get the following error:

```
./node_modules/framer-motion/dist/index.d.ts:1212:28
Type error: ';' expected.

  1210 | declare type HydratedFeatureDefinition = {
  1211 |     isEnabled: (props: MotionProps) => boolean;
> 1212 |     Feature: typeof Feature<unknown>;
      |                            ^
  1213 |     ProjectionNode?: any;
  1214 |     MeasureLayout?: typeof MeasureLayout;
  1215 | };
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem in my case was solved by bumping TypeScript from 4.3.x to 4.9.5. Hope it helps!